# This job selection problem finds the best days to work for a job where **if you work one day, you cant work the day before or after.**

Tags: game-theory

This job selection problem finds the best days to work for a job where **if you work one day, you cant work the day before or after.** The self reduction for this problem is given below:

$ JS(P[1,2,........,n])= \begin{bmatrix}  0 ,  \ \ \ if \ \ n<0 \\ P[1] , \ \ \  if \ n=1 \\ max\{P[1],P[2] \} , \ if \ \ \  n=2 \\ max\{ JS (P[1,2,......,n-2] )+P[n],JS (P[1,2,.., n-1 ]) \}, \ \ \  if \ \ n>2  \end{bmatrix} $

Then how would the self reduction change if the problem changed to $ \to \ $  **you can work 2 days in a row but you cant work the day before or after ?**

**Answer:**

The given self -reduction was for the work of  $ \  1 \ \ day  \ $.

We have to find same the formula  for $ 2 \ \ days \ $.

According to me the self-reduction for $ \ 2 \ \ days \ $ work becomes

$ JS(P[1,2,........,n])= \begin{bmatrix}  0 ,  \ \ \ if \ \ n<0 \\ P[1] , \ \ \  if \ n=1 \\ P[1]+P[2]  , \ if \ \ \  n=2 \\ max\{P[1]+P[2], \ P[1]+P[3], \ P[2]+P[3]  \}, \ \ if \ \ n=3 \\  max\{ JS (P[1,2,......,n-2] )+P[n],JS (P[1,2,.., n-1 ]) \}, \ \ \  if \ \ n>3  \end{bmatrix} $

**Am I right ?  Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite: the last term in the self-reduction still forces you to alternate days on and off. There should be three possible cases - count backwards from the last day you don't work.